# Does Crashlytics provide CPU thread state for iOS crash logs?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I cannot find this information in the portal, nor can I find any information in their knowledge base.  This seems like a rather large blind spot if it's truly missing.

Comment: Probably no, since there is no indication of this in crash logs and in Crashlytics portal. Note that SDK in app I have access too is updated probably in Nov/Dec 2014 so this may not be entirely correct. Also there may be some options which I'm not aware of.